# import wget and invalid syntax on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i am Python beginner.

I succeeded in using "image enhancing(from tensorflow lib)" running on colab and I wanted to run it on jupyter notebook, so I moved it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Dd0.png)

```
import wget "https://photos.app.goo.gl/5xYLFcdUa8k3a5p97" -O original.png
```

and when I execute "run"button and print this word

```
File "<ipython-input-19-9c130066c119>", line 1
    import wget "https://photos.app.goo.gl/5xYLFcdUa8k3a5p97" -O original.png
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i'm in a situation that make (super-resolution) system (i wanna use jupyter notebook without using colab)

Comment: `wget` is a shell command, not something to import. What are you actually trying to do because you can download images without wget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget` isn't a Python module, so you can't import it.  `urllib` is an importable Python module and can be used to retrieve internet resources such as images.

You will find it helpful to read the urllib HOWTO and other relevant Python docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html